# Complex JSON parsing in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I need to create a card in my app, but my app is a news application and calling my data from a website with JSON API, I tried to retrieve the image of the news a crash in the application and gives a message:

> Exception caught by image resource service The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///medium_large. Image provider: NetworkImage("medium_large", scale: 1.0)
>   Image key: NetworkImage("medium_large", scale: 1.0)

**What's wrong with the code? Can I simplify the code better?**

**JSON:**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "posts": [
        {
            "title": "Barcelona 0-0 Real Madrid: Bale goal disallowed in tense Clasico",
            "content": "Gareth Bale saw a goal disallowed as Barcelona and Real Madrid played out a 0-0 draw at Camp Nou on Wednesday. LaLiga's top two went into the contest level on points this season and with 72 wins each from previous league meetings, and there was nothing to separate them in a tense clash in Catalonia. The match was rearranged from October after the initial date became a security risk due to the prospect of Catalan independence protests, and there were fans inside and outside the stadium making their voices heard over one of Spain's most divisive issues.",
            "date": "2019-12-21 11:27:25",
            "thumbnail_image": {
                "medium_large": {
                    "url": "https://www.livescore.com/newsapi/04/soccer/imageret/barcelona-real-madrid-gareth-bale-goal-disallowed-tense-clasico-7-1cgsl7i8ipuf61gmt7m8ttd60w.jpg"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**News Class:**

```
class News {
  String status;
  List<Posts> posts;

  News({
    this.status,
    this.posts,
  });

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new News(
        status: json["status"],
        posts:
            new List<Posts>.from(json["posts"].map((x) => Posts.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "posts": new List<dynamic>.from(posts.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Posts {
  String title;
  String content;
  DateTime date;
  PostImage thumbnailImages;

  Posts({this.title, this.content, this.date, this.thumbnailImages});

  factory Posts.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> postsJson) => new Posts(
        title: postsJson["title"],
        content: postsJson["content"] == null ? null : postsJson["content"],
        date: DateTime.parse(postsJson["date"]),
        thumbnailImages: PostImage.fromJson(postsJson["thumbnail_images"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "content": content == null ? null : content,
        "date": date.toIso8601String(),
        "thumbnail_images": thumbnailImages.toJson(),
      };
}

class PostImage {
  String mediumImage;
  String url;

  PostImage({ this.mediumImage, this.url });

  factory PostImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> imgJson) => new PostImage(
      mediumImage: "medium_large",
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "medium_large": mediumImage,
  };
}
```

**ListNews:**

```
class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Posts posts;

  ListItem(this.posts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Row(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 400,
          width: 220,
          child: Image.network(posts.thumbnailImages.mediumImage),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    posts.title,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding .url

```
child: Image.network(posts.thumbnailImages.mediumImage.url),
```

**Working code:**
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/haidar786/30b775e64af2ca7951774938ab31dc25)

Comment: If I need to add JSON URL in `final posts = News.fromJson()`, how can I do that?

Comment: Get response first then add into fromJson function. For details https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Comment: Do can edit your answer to how can I do that, please!!

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, I can wait for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204760/discussion-between-hussnain-haidar-and-developer1996).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `PostImage` class. and add another class `MediumLarge`

```
class PostImage {
  MediumLarge mediumLarge;

  PostImage({
    this.mediumLarge,
  });

  factory PostImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostImage(
        mediumLarge: MediumLarge.fromJson(json["medium_large"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "medium_large": mediumLarge.toJson(),
      };
}

class MediumLarge {
  String url;

  MediumLarge({
    this.url,
  });

  factory MediumLarge.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MediumLarge(
        url: json["url"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "url": url,
      };
}
```

and then use

```
Container(
  height: 400,
  width: 220,
  child: Image.network(posts.thumbnailImages.mediumImage.url),
)
```

There is a website that generates dart classes for the json. [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/)